# How to make curry always come out dry\easily remove extra water?

Tags: water, curry

When I cook a curry I add water to help it cook and stop burning if it goes to low etc.  However I prefer my currys to be dry i.e where most water has evaporated.

I know you can just cook with less water to begin and cook slow or always watch the curry adding a little water but i'm wondering if the result can be achieved with less effort.

1. Are there any tools I could use which will allow me too cook and dry out a curry(leaving oil) in the same way a rice cooker dries out water?
2. In case where to much water has been added and the curry is complete, the best I can think of is to remove the liquid to another pot(saves accidentaly burning meat) and boil it down and then add remaining liquid back to pot(since i need oil\fat and other nutrients minus water)?  Can you think of an easier method to accomplish what i'm trying?

Answer (score 3):

I always just let the curry simmer in a pot with the lid off to let the water evaporate more so I have thicker curries. The other option (and this is what my Indian family does) is to pour the liquid (so leave out the potatoes, chicken, whatever..) into a smaller pan and bring it to a rolling boil for a while to reduce the gravy and let it thicken. Finally, add in the rest of the ingredients when it is as thick as you want it.